# Close Button overlay on Leadbolt ad

Tags: html, css, leadbolt

Im using Leadbolts HTML Ads on my mobile App.
Currently it looks like this:

[image]

*What I am trying to achieve is put an X into the top right, so that the user can close the ad.*

The code for the ads looks like this:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.leadboltmobile.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=619553414"></script>
</body>
```

---

First i tried to put an image on top of it like this:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <img id="x" src="@routes.Assets.at("images/x.png")" onclick="closeAd()"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.leadboltmobile.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=619553414"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#x {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Even though the image is absolutly positioned it doesn`t show up at all.

---

Then i tried to wrap the ad in a div.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <img id="x" src="@routes.Assets.at("images/x.png")" onclick="closeAd()"/>
  <div id="adWrapper">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.leadboltmobile.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=619553414"></script>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#x {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#adWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
}
```

But the ad is still displayed fullscreen as shown in the image.

Could somebody help me out here?

Comment: Have you tried setting a z-index for the image? It might help

Comment: Wow the z-index did the Trick!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A higher `z-index` than the `#adWrapper` will fix it. Use `z-index` this way:

```
#x {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#adWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```